# WARNING: File "/xmlrpc.php" is not readable - any ideas what to do here?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress installation and I use a plugin called Backup Wordpress, which - backs up WordPress!

So - the other day I received an error that said:

WARNING: File "path-to/xmlrpc.php" is not readable

any ideas what this is and how to fix it? I guess I can go into the relevant directory and FTP and change the file permissions - but is that wise for this file?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xmlrpc.php needs to be readable by the web server processes. Ensure that it has appropriate file ownership and permissions. For a debian-based server, a command like `sudo chown www-data:www-data xmlrpc && sudo chmod 644 xmlrpc.php` will probably resolve this.

Comment: yes, in fact the xmlrpc.php had no file permissions.

Seems odd - why would that happen? Maybe a wordpress update wrote over the old xmlrpc?

Comment: More likely a bug in a plugin than in WordPress itself... I could hardly speculate though. So your issue is resolved?

Comment: ownership is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Simple 644 file permissions fixed this.

Not sure why the file permissions was re-set to 000

Comment: This is essentially what Matthew answered. You should accept his answer instead of posting your own.